# SQL - if statement only

Tags: mysql, sql, if-statement, null

I need to set `if-statement` without `else` part in SQL query. But `if-statement` syntax is `IF(<condtion>, <true part>, <false part>)`. I do not have (not need to set) any value for else part.

**Example:** From user table, if user id is greater than 0 then only I need to add user id. How can I implement/add such condition?

```
SELECT
    u.fname,
    u.lname,
    IF(u.id>0, u.id, ? )  // Here I do not have value for else part.
FROM
    user_table u;
```

Comment: Why do you just put a null there

Comment: You want a table where different rows can have different number of columns?

Comment: I think you have to put null in else part because its picking up the column and either you choose the value or put null at that place.

Comment: @Khalil unable to understand your que.

Comment: @Johnyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy I'm getting values from table but I don't need to get value where value is 0. Can I use `null` over there? how?

Comment: @Krunal tadman's answer is what I meant

Comment: see tadman's answer.

Comment: Sorry didn't understood why you said in comment? . Answer of tadman is just like what I said

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each column in the result row must contain a value even if that value is `NULL`:

```
SELECT fname, lname, IF(id>0, id, NULL) AS id FROM user_table;
```

A result set contains a number of rows and one of the constraints is these rows must have an identical number of columns with identical definitions.